# Django - output a calculation

Tags: html, django, render, aggregation, calculation

I'm trying to output in html a calculation which is based on 2 aggregations (sums)
Though, it doesn't display (typerror). Can someone help me out?

in views.py: (extract)

```
def calcul(request, slug):
   numerator = CF.objects.filter(type='inflow').aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))
   calculation = numerator / Main.objects.filter(slug=slug).aggregate(sum=Sum('total')
   return render(request, 'home/detail.html', { 'calculation' : calculation})
```

in my template :

```
{{ calculation }}
```

Comment: Please fix your function indentation. It also would help if you post the complete error message.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation. Basically it just doesn't run at all

Comment: That means that your numerator is a dictionary, log your `numerator` to check the value. What kind of data has the CF model? Also, add the error to the question body, and in your calculation line you are missing a final `)`

Comment: I've corrected the )  -> thanks. Actually the error is "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'dict'". So i understand this means i have 2 dictionaries. The CF model only has integers in the 'amount' attribute. How can I check the log?

Comment: The easiest way is to print it to console, `print(numerator)` for example. I added it as a response for easier explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) will output a dict, if you add `print(numerator)` after it you will see the dict `{'sum': <value>}` (the same with the denominator).

You need to access the value and then use it:

```
def calcul(request, slug):
   numerator = CF.objects.filter(type='inflow').aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']
   denominator = Main.objects.filter(slug=slug).aggregate(sum=Sum('total'))['sum']
   try:
       calculation = numerator / denominator
   except ZeroDivisionError:
       calculation = 0
   return render(request, 'home/detail.html', { 'calculation' : calculation})
```

Comment: You may want to check for zero values as well.

Comment: thanks to you as well! it worked ! last question: how to output it as a % and not  a float?

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation returns dictionary so you should take the value out and then do the calculation:

```
def calcul(request, slug):
    numerator = CF.objects.filter(type='inflow').aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))
    calculation = numerator['sum'] / Main.objects.filter(slug=slug).aggregate(sum=Sum('total')['sum']
    return render(request, 'home/detail.html', { 'calculation' : calculation})
```

Comment: OK sounds correct (and in line with django documentation), but now I receive a Key error: Exception value on 'sum'

Comment: print `numerator` and `Main.objects.filter(slug=slug).aggregate(sum=Sum('total')` and check for the key. it might be different. if it was, change `['sum']` to the key you got from printing the values.

Comment: thanks it worked ! Last question : how to output is a % instead as a float?

Comment: not sure what you mean but you can turn any int to float using `float(an_int)`. Maybe you mean this: `(numerator['sum'] * 100.00) / Main.objects.filter(slug=slug).aggregate(sum=Sum('total')['sum']`

Comment: Hi Navid. For instance currently a 60/100 is presented in the  browser as 0.6. though, I would like it to be presented as 60% . thanks  !

Comment: `str(number * 100) + "%"`